# Times in latin: in 4 hours, at 4, until 4, from 4

Tags: time

How do I refer to certain hours, like for example:

*In 4 hours = (in) quattuor hora
Here I would use ablative with 'in'

*Until 4 o clock = ad quattuor horam
Here I would use accusative due to 'ad' with a meaning of 'to'

*At 4 o clock = ?

*From 4 o clock = (ab) quattuor hora
Here I would use ablative with 'ab'

My questions:

1. Are my translations correct?
2. How do I say 'At 4 o clock'?
3. How would one make a dofference between:
   -'since four hours' he bugged me
   and
   -'from four o clock' until 3 he bugged me

I assume I'm thinking way too deep and complex about this somehow

Comment: Just a quick note: the fourth hour is *not* the same as our 4 o'clock. The Romans did not start counting at midnight. Here's a link on Roman timekeeping: http://penelope.uchicago.edu/Thayer/E/Roman/Texts/secondary/SMIGRA*/Hora.html

Comment: As Sebastian Koppehel says in his answer, you should use the plural with quattuor, so *in quattuor horis*

Comment: Also it's worth remembering that cardinal numbers are also adjectives, and while quattuor, like most, happens to be undeclined, *unus, duo* and *tres* are not, so it's *unam horam, duabus/tribus horis*, etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While Manuel's answer is essentially correct, I believe some elaboration may be helpful. It is true that in Latin, you generally use *ordinal* numbers for hours (as for years, by the way!), so you say *prima, secunda, tertia, quarta hora*, etc., and not *quattuor hora*. Note that you can also simply write a number (in Roman numerals preferrably, of course), e.g. *IV hora*, but if you read it out loud, it is *quarta*.

As cmw remarks in a comment, the Romans counted the hours of the day from sunrise to sunset, so *quarta hora* is the fourth hour of the day – depending on the time of the year, somewhat before or after 10 o' clock in the morning (Wikipedia has a [nice illustration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Ancient_Roman_time_keeping_hora_vigilia_equinox_solstice.svg) of the effect) – which has little to do with our idea of 4 o' clock. When speaking of our modern 24-hour day, I would recommend adding *ante aut post meridiem* (which you can of course abbreviate as *a.m.* and *p.m.*, respectively) to make it unambiguous you are talking about modern hours. The adjectives *antemeridianus* and *postmeridianus* are also possible. The Romans also sometimes said *hora diei* instead of simple *hora*, which I would avoid doing unless I was using their system.

Now to your questions:

- To say “at the fourth hour,” you use the ablative:, e.g. *hora quarta Brundisium venimus* (Cicero, [*Ad familiares* 16, 9, 2](https://www.thelatinlibrary.com/cicero/fam16.shtml#lnine)). To say “at 4 o' clock p.m.,” like I said, I would recommend *quarta hora post meridiem*.
- To say “from,” you do indeed use *ab*, and for “until,” indeed *ad* or *usque ad*, e.g. *cum ab hora fere quarta usque ad solis occasum pugnaretur* (Caesar, [*De bello Gallico* 3, 15](https://www.thelatinlibrary.com/caesar/gall3.shtml#15); references to *hora duodecima* seem to have often been avoided in favour of *solis occasus*)
- “In 4 hours” can be expressed with the ablative: *quattuor horis* (e.g. *quattuor horis redibo*). If it means "within 4 hours," you can also say *in* + abl., or *intra* or *inter* (both with the accusative).
- “Since four hours he bugged me” sounds quite strange to me and I'm not sure what it means; if you want to say “He has been bugging me for four hours,” I would say *quattuor iam horas mihi oneri est* or *quinta iam hora* (four hours completed, we are now in the fifth).

Answer (score 3):

What do you mean by "in 4 hours"?

"Until 4 o'clock "you can say "usque ad horam quartam"

"At 4 o'clock" "hora quarta" ablative case

"From 4 o'clock" "ab hora quarta"

"Since 4 hours" "abhinc quattuor horas"

"From 4 o'clock until 3 he bugged me"
"Ab hora quarta usque ad horam tertiam is me irritavit"

Comment: Let's assume "in 4 hours" means 4 hours from now (e.g. it is quarter past two, then that would be quarter past six). How would you translate that?

Comment: Hora sexta et quadrans est. I hate to suggest that,  but you can whatch the Scorpio martianus video a about telling time, or just Google telling time in latin.